# Attributing the selected item to a certain type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, boxing

I've got a combo box with items of type *Something*. Upon an event, I want to assign that item to a variable. At the moment, since *SelectedItem* is of type *Object*, I need to unbox it to the desired type like this.

```
Something something = ThatComboBox.SelectedItem as Something;
```

It's even more inconvenient should the type by an enum, because then I need to either cast or nullable-fy it and then coalesce like so.

```
Something something;
  something = (Something)ThatComboBox.SelectedItem;
  something = ThatComboBox.SelectedItem as Something? ?? default(Something);
```

I wonder if I can (and if so how I go about it) attribute (or such) the combo box so that when I get its selected item I get it as whatever type my heart desire. Or, at the very least, the type it was prior the boxing.

Please note that I wonder if I can do so **without** extension methods.

Comment: `I need to unbox` Does your `Something` of non-nullable value type? If so, you can't use `as`.

Comment: You could certainly subclass `ComboBox` and create a generic version and define a new `SelectedItem` property that does that for you, but it does seem like alot of work for something so trivial. An extension method would be way easier.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm pretty sure I can. Did you see the second code snippet? In any case, the question is how to avoid the necessity of *as*-ing and casting independent of whether it's a nullable or not.

Comment: @Chris I agree with you. In fact, I **am** using an extension method. The question is asked because I was wondering if there's an even more smooth method, e.g. setting a property of something to the type. I'm guessing the answer is "no". Thanks mate!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yeah, I'm afraid no run-time property is going to be able to change the type at compile time!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yeah, it's stated there that one can nullable-fy a type by the "?" operator and then coalesce it by the "??" operator using *default* keyword. So I think that the docs agree with me.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBox.SelectedItem` has the type `object` so it may contain a reference to **any** type (or null).

The `as` oerator does no work at all, just enables the compiler to treat the reference as a reference to another type (in your case a reference to Something).

There is no runtime overhead involved, just one more line in your source code. I can't see a point why/how to avoid that.

Comment: The point was to avoid nullable-fying and subsequently coalescing the value before the assignment (and also to avoid casting). The reason behind the former is that it looks less readable. The latter is because I don't trust people not to change the types irresponsibly.